# PrimEng Backend requirements

Tags: node.js, primeng

Did some searching and still having a problem findind a definitive answer, was hoping someone here could help. Does `PrimeEng` require `Nodejs` as it's backend ? Is there a way to utilize the UI components only. We have run in a custom o/s environment, hence running nodejs on the backend is not an option.

Comment: No, PrimeNG does not require node.js at all.

Answer (score 1):

Ok did more digging. Setup on IIS was not working due to mime issue. So the answer is the UI components are self contained. In case this answers someone else's question on the matter.